# complex numbers: why isnt this working?

Tags: java, android, complex-numbers

When i load up this code and input some numbers and try to add the complex numbers, it force closes the app.

```
public void complex3(View v){

    EditText numAA=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.complextest1);
    EditText numBB=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.complextest2);
    EditText numCC=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.complextest3);
    EditText numDD=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.complextest4);
    Double num1=Double.parseDouble(numAA.getText().toString()) ,
            num2=Double.parseDouble(numBB.getText().toString()),
            num3=Double.parseDouble(numCC.getText().toString()),
            num4=Double.parseDouble(numDD.getText().toString());
    Complex a = new Complex(num1,num2);
    Complex b = new Complex(num3,num4);
    Complex c = Complexadd(a,b);
    TextView X=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.complexanswertest);
    X.setText("X= "+new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(c));
}

private Complex Complexadd(Complex a, Complex b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you are getting an exception, please show it.

Comment: I don't recognize EditText or TextView. I do recognize 'R', so I assume this is for Android? You should maybe tag it as such, as you'll get more help. Is Complex from Apache Commons Math?

Comment: Post your adb logcat output for this

Comment: you should tag has android since look like to me you coding for android and you should give more explanation if you are inside a activity or a simple class that you define your method and you pass value from a activity to somewhere.

Comment: `Complexadd` returns `null`. Passing `null` to `format` causes the crash.

Answer (score 1):

You will obviously get `NullPointerException`

Here

```
Complex c = Complexadd(a,b);<------- C will be null

X.setText("X= "+new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(c));<----NPE
```

Because C is Null.

```
  private Complex Complexadd(Complex a, Complex b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;//Do addition of Complex Numbers and Return Complex here
    }
```

Comment: This is for android yes. The second part of the code is what Eclipse put in for the method of Complexadd. So what do i change to make this work? Im just trying to add two complex numbers. EditText and TextView are parts of eclipse.

Comment: The logcat is too long but it says "Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity." and "Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-31 19:36:27.553: E/AndroidRuntime(842):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)"